# Store tokens to access other applications on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a rest application in Spring Boot, with security configured and JWT tokens implemented for the services it exposes. But this application also connects to other 3rd party applications, also secured with JWT and with different tokens per application.

My question is: what is the best strategy to store these 3rd party tokens? Is there something like `SecurityContextHolder`, but for storing the tokens that the application uses to authenticate on other services?

Answer (score 0):

While configuring your

```
OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate
```

You can persist the token in the client

```
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new 
    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
    AccessTokenProviderChain provider = new 
    AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.asList(new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider()));
    provider.setClientTokenServices(clientTokenServices());
    return template;
}
```

As described by in spring security oauth docs [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

> **Persisting Tokens in a Client**
>
> A client does not need to persist tokens, but it can be nice for users to not be required to approve a new token grant every time the client app is restarted. The ClientTokenServices interface defines the operations that are necessary to persist OAuth 2.0 tokens for specific users. There is a JDBC implementation provided, but you can if you prefer implement your own service for storing the access tokens and associated authentication instances in a persistent database. If you want to use this feature you need provide a specially configured TokenProvider to the OAuth2RestTemplate